# Syntax to create a dict or set in comprehensions

Tags: python-2.7, syntax

In Python 2.7.15:

```
>>> dict((s, len(s)) for s in ['aa', 'b', 'cccc'])
{'aa': 2, 'cccc': 4, 'b': 1}

>>> {(s, len(s)) for s in ['aa', 'b', 'cccc']}
set([('b', 1), ('aa', 2), ('cccc', 4)])
```

Why does `dict()` create a dictionary, but `{}` creates a set? I thought those two syntaxes were synonymous.

Comment: By using dict you are specifying the key:value pair when doing the list comprehension, whereas when using the {} is naming elements within that set which are not necessarily key:value pairs. [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370599/difference-between-dict-and-set-python) goes into more detail about why that is the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between dict and set (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370599/difference-between-dict-and-set-python)