# How to split the textfile

Tags: python, file, dictionary, split, average

04-05-1993:1.068

04-12-1993:1.079

04-19-1993:1.079

06-06-1994:1.065

06-13-1994:1.073

06-20-1994:1.079

---

I have text file for date-year-price for gas and i want to calculate the avg gas prices for year. So i tried to split,

```
with open('c:/Gasprices.txt','r') as f: 
   fullfile=[x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
datesprices=[(x.split('-')[0], x.split(':')[1]) for x in fullfile]
print(datesprices)
```

But I can't get year and price data but data like this.

```
('04', '1.068'), ('04', '1.079')
```

please let me know what should i know.

and plus, please let me know how to use split data to calculate the avg price per year using a dictionary if you can.

Comment: `x.split('-')[0]` gives you the day, use `x.split('-')[2]` to get the year.

Comment: @TitouanL This will give `'1993:1.068'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no need to split the input lines as they have a fixed format for the date - i.e., its length is known. Therefore we can just slice.

```
with open('gas.txt') as gas:
    td = dict()
    for line in gas:
        year = line[6:10]
        price = float(line[11:])
        td.setdefault(year, []).append(price)
    for k, v in td.items():
        print(f'{k} {sum(v)/len(v):.3f}')
```

**Output:**

```
1993 1.075
1994 1.072
```

**Note:**

There is no check here for blank lines. It is assumed that there are none and that the sample shown in the question is malformed.

Also, no need to strip the incoming lines as *float()* is impervious to leading/trailing whitespace

Comment: I got output well, but i can't understand the code. Can you explain what td=dict() means?

Comment: @Seb It assigns a reference to an empty dictionary to a variable named *td*. You may find this interesting:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370599/difference-between-dict-and-set-python

Answer (score 1):

As it was already mentioned, to get the year you should use a bit more complex split. But your format seems to be very consistent, you could probably go for:

```
datesprices=[(x[6:10], x[11:]) for x in fullfile]
```

but how to get average of it? You need to store list for specific year somewhere.

```
from statistics import mean

my_dict = {} # could be defaultdict too
for year, price in datesprices:
    if year not in my_dict:
        my_dict[year] = []
    my_dict[year].append(price)

for year, prices in my_dict.items():
    print(year, mean(prices))
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```py
with open('c:/Gasprices.txt','r') as f: 
    fullfile=[x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
datesprices=[(x.split('-')[0],x.split('-')[-1].split(':')[0], x.split(':')[1]) for x in fullfile]
print(datesprices)
```

OUTPUT

```
[('04', '1993', '1.068'), ('04', '1993', '1.079'), ('04', '1993', '1.079'), ('06', '1994', '1.065'), ('06', '1994', '1.073'), ('06', '1994', '1.079')]
```

OR

```py
with open('c:/Gasprices.txt','r') as f: 
    fullfile=[x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
datesprices=[(x.split('-')[-1].split(':')[0], x.split(':')[1]) for x in fullfile]
print(datesprices)
```

OUTPUT

```
[('1993', '1.068'), ('1993', '1.079'), ('1993', '1.079'), ('1994', '1.065'), ('1994', '1.073'), ('1994', '1.079')]
```

Comment: I think the author wants only year and price, in order to get the average price for each year.

Comment: @lemon Thnx, I Added for both.

Answer (score 0):

```
    txt = ['04-05-1993:1.068', '04-12-1993:1.079', '04-19-1993:1.079', '06-06-1994:1.065', '06-13-1994:1.073', '06-20-1994:1.079']

    price_per_year = {}
    number_of_years = {}
    for i in txt:
      x = txt.split(':')
      Date = x[0]
      Price = x[1]
      year = date.split('-')[2]

      if year ~in price_per_year.keys:
        price_per_year.update({year:Price})
        number_of_years.update({year:1})
      else:
        price_per_year[year] += Price
        number_of_years[year] += 1
 
av_price_1993 = price_per_year[1993] / number_of_years[1993]
av_price_1994
 = price_per_year[1994] / number_of_years[1994]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).